# Android XML parsing

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I have a problem with parsing xml by an android, a document that is parsed well with Java EE, do not want parsed into an android. Using SAX. Maybe someone encountered this problem.

Comment: you want to get xml doc to string?

Comment: Yes. But it well working in java ee, not in android. I used the same libraries

Comment: You need to give some more detail.

Comment: I tried parse this http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=miami, JavaEE finded all tags? but Android only first two, and next seems as "poblem_cause" and skip inner block

Comment: SaxHandler: http://pastebin.com/mmZqRg78 , activity: http://pastebin.com/FP8Wv2Cg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had real truble with this too...
For getting xml document to string, i'm using this library:
http://wurstgranulat.de/projekte/java-library-android-xml-document-string/

fo creating document i use dom parser:
http://www.java.happycodings.com/XML/code17.html

Comment: i've been past hundreds of tutorials and posts here and on other blogs and sites, then i found this library and it works fine =)

Comment: Its get XML as data array? I cant try it now )

Comment: what? you have doc and you convert it to string...there is no arrays